# How to create an automtic CloudWatch Alarm every time an EC2 instance with some name is launched?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

Background :

- I have an EC2 instance called "Test Host". I want monitor the health of this host. So I am using the EC2 metric [StatusCheckFailed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) to monitor the health of this host.

The problem I am trying to solve is :

- Whenever there is an issue with "Test Host" I will be notified. I might terminate and relaunch a new host with the name "Test Host"
- What I want to achieve is as soon I create a new host with the name "Test Host" I want a StatusCheckFailed alarm to be automatically be created on CloudWatch.

Things I tried so far :

I was able to write a small Lambda python script that finds the EC2 instance with name "Test Host" and creates StatusCheckFailed a CloudWatch alarm.

**I am not able to find a suitable CloudWatch event that will trigger this Lambda function. [For setting the CloudWatch event we need instance id. If I terminate and relaunch a new instance I will not be able to set this up]**

Also if there is any alternate way to solve my problem, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **Amazon CloudWatch Events rule** that will trigger an AWS Lambda function when an instance enters a particular state:

[image: CloudWatch Events rule]

However, this will also trigger whenever an instance is stopped and then started. You could be more specific and create a rule based on `RunInstances`:

[image: CloudWatch Events rule]

I'm not sure whether `RunInstances` is sufficient, or whether it would need to be `ec2:RunInstances`, so you might need to experiment a bit.